# Selecting two columns gives duplicates in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following structure:

ChatMessages table:

```
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 Id        | text                        |           | not null |
 SenderId  | text                        |           |          |
 Message   | text                        |           |          |
 ChatId    | text                        |           |          |
 CreatedAt | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "PK_ChatMessages" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")
    "IX_ChatMessages_ChatId" btree ("ChatId")
    "IX_ChatMessages_SenderId" btree ("SenderId")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_ChatMessages_ChatUsers_SenderId" FOREIGN KEY ("SenderId") REFERENCES "ChatUsers"("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "FK_ChatMessages_Chats_ChatId" FOREIGN KEY ("ChatId") REFERENCES "Chats"("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

ChatUsers table:

```
  Column   |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 Id        | text                        |           | not null |
 Username  | text                        |           |          |
 Email     | text                        |           |          |
 CreatedAt | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "PK_ChatUsers" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""ChatMessages"" CONSTRAINT "FK_ChatMessages_ChatUsers_SenderId" FOREIGN KEY ("SenderId") REFERENCES "ChatUsers"("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
    TABLE ""Chats"" CONSTRAINT "FK_Chats_ChatUsers_User1Id" FOREIGN KEY ("User1Id") REFERENCES "ChatUsers"("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
    TABLE ""Chats"" CONSTRAINT "FK_Chats_ChatUsers_User2Id" FOREIGN KEY ("User2Id") REFERENCES "ChatUsers"("Id") ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

If I execute `select "SenderId", "Email", "Message" from "ChatMessages", "ChatUsers";` I receive a list with all messages, however each message is multiplied by the amount of users' email addresses:

```
               SenderId               |        Email        |                        Message
--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user1@example.com | This is a test message.
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user1@example.com | This is also a test message.
 b3e218e6-dd41-4223-978b-a54f46fc465e | user1@example.com | okay ...
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user2@example.com | This is a test message.
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user2@example.com | This is also a test message.
 b3e218e6-dd41-4223-978b-a54f46fc465e | user2@example.com | okay ...
```

However, I want it to be displayed like the following:

```
               SenderId               |        Email        |                        Message
--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user1@example.com   | This is a test message.
 2f5aca90-0599-400c-8455-31a22c1d4dcd | user1@example.com   | This is also a test message.
 b3e218e6-dd41-4223-978b-a54f46fc465e | user2@example.com   | okay ...
```

What would be the correct query for that?

Comment: You are not making a join between the 2 tables. That I think is the problem.

Comment: @WilliamAndrésBernal l usually do not write the sql myself because I am using a ORM. I read the documentation and ```select * from one_table, another_table;``` is a new syntax instead of using the join syntaxt. However it might be that I have to use another join type like right, left, outer, etc.

Comment: As your results show, it is not making the JOIN automatically, for example "This is a test message" is with both senders. I would just put a simple JOIN as defined in the FKs

Comment: @WilliamAndrésBernal Which join type do I need for this?

Comment: try with this (postgres syntax):
SELECT cm.SenderId, cu.Email, cm.Message
FROM ChatMessages cm JOIN ChatUsers cu
ON cm.SenderId = cu.Id

Comment: Alright, I got it. As you said I have to use the join syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this (postgres syntax):

```
SELECT cm.SenderId, cu.Email, cm.Message FROM ChatMessages cm JOIN ChatUsers cu ON cm.SenderId = cu.Id
```